# I have trouble printing chart in PDF format or the other

Tags: javascript, css, html, infragistics, ignite

I have this chart:
[image]

I press the button to print what is displayed.
[image]

Recommend a good solution for this problem.
And here is the code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnPrint").click(function () {
                var contents = $("#dvContents").html();
                var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
                frame1[0].name = "frame1";
                frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
                $("body").append(frame1);
                var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
                frameDoc.document.open();
                //Create a new HTML document.
                frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title></head>');
                frameDoc.document.write('<body>');
                //Append the external CSS file.
                frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="Infragistics/css/structure/infragistics.css" />');
                frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="Infragistics/css/structure/modules/infragistics.ui.chart1.css" />');
                frameDoc.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"/>');
                frameDoc.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/>');
                frameDoc.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"/>');
                //Append the DIV contents.
                frameDoc.document.write(contents);
                frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
                frameDoc.document.close();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                    window.frames["frame1"].print();
                    frame1.remove();
                }, 500);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Thank you, Best Regards

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try.